# Command pyinstaller --clean xyz.spec, exe gets created successfully but when executing no logging in console

Tags: python, pyinstaller

After I create the exe when I run the exe the application exits immediately although its getting processed in the background. I can see after a while the log file gets generated but I don't see any logging in the console.
I tried adding explicit sys.out logging handler but that hasn't worked as well. Here is my code for logging

```
def set_logger(logname, logLevel):
    try:
        # set log level for console output
        log_format = ('%(levelname)s - %(asctime)s - %(module)s - Line number %(lineno)d - %(message)s')
        bold_seq = '\033[1m'
        colorlog_format = (
            f'{bold_seq} '
            '%(log_color)s '
            f'{log_format}'
        )
        colorlog.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, format=colorlog_format)
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logLevelSwitch = {
            "debug": logging.DEBUG,
            "info": logging.INFO,
            "warning": logging.WARNING,
            "error": logging.ERROR,
            "critical": logging.CRITICAL,
        }
        logger.setLevel(logLevelSwitch.get(logLevel.lower()))
        # create file handler which will log to a file
        fh = logging.FileHandler(logname)
        fh.setLevel(logLevelSwitch.get(logLevel.lower()))
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s - %(asctime)s - %(module)s - Line number %(lineno)d - %(message)s')
        fh.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(fh)
    except Exception as e:
        print(list([str(datetime.datetime.now()), 'FUNCTION_NAME:setlogger, ERROR_MSG:', str(e)]))
```

The logging in file works correctly but when I run the exe either via powershell or cmd it just exits immediately and logging doesn't appear in the console.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was in the spec file. So when I run the command pyinstaller --clean xyz.spec there is a property in the spec file called exe and this property takes in a parameter called console. By default it was set to false. When I set it to true the console logging started to work and the exe simply did not exit as it used to do previously.
This is the content of the exe property in spec file:

```
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      [],
      name='omst_batch_checks',
      debug=False,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      upx_exclude=[],
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=True )
```